# Invalid time value when using date-fns package

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

There's a particular date "2025-08-01" which is throwing a `RangeError: Invalid time value` when being used in the date-fns package.  Any clue around why this might be happening?

```
const dfs = require('date-fns');
new Date("2025-08-01") // works
dfs.format("2025-08-01", 'MM-yyyy'); // throws RangeError: Invalid time value
```

https://runkit.com/embed/ub1wub4pnkjk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string to the `format` function in the `date-fns` package, while it expects a `Date` object as its first argument. To fix the error, you should create a `Date` object and pass it to the `format` function like this:

```
const dfs = require('date-fns');
const date = new Date("2025-08-01"); // Create a Date object
console.log(dfs.format(date, 'MM-yyyy')); // Format the Date object
```

Reference: [date-fns docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format#syntax)